# Time series problem with LSTM is not predicting correctly

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, lstm

.

**My Initial dataset looks like this:**

[image: Initial Dataset]

Text sample of Dataset:

```
    TranDate    TradeAmount
0   2017-01-01  525.00
1   2017-01-02  131.20
2   2017-01-03  904.00
3   2017-01-04  900.00
4   2017-01-05  1354.38
```

I have to predict the **TradeAmount** for next day. based on past 60 days.

X = [past trade amounts of 60 days]

y = [trade amount of next day]

I have total 1122 data.

I tried with LSTM like this:

```
days = 60
df.sort_values(by ='TranDate',inplace=True)
data = df.filter(['TradeAmount'])

          ...............

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True,input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size = 950,epochs=1000,shuffle = True)
```

> I tried with epochs=100/500/800. batch_size = 32/256/500. It was giving a mean value of all inputs.

**The above code is giving output like:**
[image: Output]

**Textual Form:**

```
    TradeAmount Predictions
1010    120.3   1464.579956
1011    5422.8  728.806152
1012    300.0   91.881477
1013    699.5   411.360626
1014    361.5   558.223267
... ... ...
1117    4194.0  1153.897339
1118    120.3   670.037781
1119    1504.9  631.024292
1120    1634.6  36.828255
1121    180.6   495.607788
```

Predicted value is far away from original. How can I improve this??

Comment: Get more features, unless you have very specific (periodical, return to the mean) patterns you are unlikely to get something usefull from just time.

Comment: okay. trying to gather more features. thnk u @lcrmorin